# How to read dataframe using shell file with wget?

Tags: dataframe, shell, wget

I have a shell file wit code like this in it:

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt \
"https://docs.google... train.tar.gz
```

How to run this file to get my data? I know pd.read_csv but in this case I dont really get how to run it. Im using visual studio code

Comment: it depends on your shell, for bash `source filename`

Comment: @rioV8 yeah its bash. what do you mean source filename ?

Comment: `source` is a buildin bash command to read the content of a file and execute it as commands, can be abbreviated to `. filename`, `.` is an alias for `source`